# I statements and arrays using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have an array of zeros like this:

```
$a = array(0 , 0 , 0 , 0 );
```

I want an if statement that is about like this:

```
if ($a == 0) { 
    // all elements of $k be equal to zero
    //do something;
}
else {
    //do not do something!!!;
}
```

How it can be possible using `foreach`?

Comment: What does `$a == 0` mean? All of the elements equal 0?

Comment: do you mean `$a == 0` you want to find is there any other values apart from zero?

Comment: What's the question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simple foreach loop like:

```
$a = array(0 , 0 , 0 , 0, 1);

foreach($a as $el){
    if ($el == 0){
        //do something;
        echo 'ok'.PHP_EOL;
    }else{
        echo 'no'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
ok
ok
ok
ok
no
```

If you need check them all at once:

```
$a = [0,0,0,0,0];
$u = array_unique($a);

if(count($u) == 1 && $u[0] == 0){
    //do something;
    echo 'ok'.PHP_EOL;
} else {  
    echo 'no'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Outputs:

```
ok
```

Comment: Why no in the output?

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth, it was my special input array)

Comment: i want to know that if all member of a's array is 0, then do something not exactly that u said but thanks

Comment: @AksenP Nice. Cache the `array_unique($a)` result to make it more faster.

Answer (score 1):

use array_unique($a) to remove the duplicate values of 0 it will reduce your loop and give you fast output. after that you can use

```
 $b = array_unique($a);
foreach($b as $el){
   if ($el == 0){
    //do something;
    echo 'ok'.PHP_EOL;
  }else{
    echo 'no'.PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice. I think you can avoid the foreach and make your code more concise. https://3v4l.org/RBRUe

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_filter` to remove all `0` elements

```
$a = array(0 , 0 , 0 , 0);
if (count(array_filter($a)) == 0) {
    // do something if all elements are 0
    echo "Contains all zero elements";
}
else {
    // do something
    echo "Contains non zero elements";
}
```

here is the [demo](https://3v4l.org/OPnfD)

Comment: This is a correct solution. Just a side note that passing no callback to array_filter would even filter out all values which evaluate to false, like `NULL`, `false`, `array()` etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function all_zeros(array $items) {
    $unique = array_unique($items);

    return $unique === [0];
}

var_dump(all_zeros([0,0,0,0]));
var_dump(all_zeros([0,0,0,1]));
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

So for your example:

```
$a = array(0, 0, 0, 0);
if(array_unique($a) === [0]) {
    echo 'all zeros.';
}
```

Output:

```
all zeros.
```

If you have an array consisting only of integers, it may be more performant to flip the array.  An array of 0's will be reduced to one item, with a 0 index.

```
$flipped = array_flip(array(0, 0, 0, 0));
if(isset($flipped[0]) && count($flipped) === 1) {
    // all zeros
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:-**

```
$a = array(0, 0, 30 , 40 );
if (in_array(0,$a)){
   echo "0 is exists";
}else{
   echo "0 is not exists";
}
```

Comment: I think OP wants to check if all array elements are zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function test($a)
{
  $arraySize = sizeOf($a);
  $countOfNumWithZero;
  $message = "";

  foreach($a as $val)
  {
      ($val === 0) ? $countOfNumWithZero++ : null;        

      $message = ($arraySize === $countOfNumWithZero) ? "This is all zeroes" : "This contain a non zero";                
  }
  return $message;
}

$val1 = array(0, 0 , 0, 0, 0);
$val2 = array(0, 0 , 0, 0, 1);
$val3 = array(0, 0 , -1, 0, 1);


echo test($val1);
echo test($val2);
echo test($val3);
```

The output is this

```
This is all zeroes
This contain a non zero
This contain a non zero
```

Comment: What if input will be `$a = array(0, 0 , 1, 0, -1);`

Comment: Thanks Progrock. Your solution is very neat and simplified :D.